# Is there a way to make MonoTouch (runtime and associated library) a consumed and referenced library in a standard iOS project/application?

Tags: iphone, ios, xamarin.ios

I'm liking Monotouch and would like to have an app that mixes both objective c and Monotouch.

I've seen examples of MonoTouch apps that reference and consume static iOS libs, but is the opposite possible?

i.e. Is it possible to have an iOS Xcode project that runs the MonoTouch runtime and consumes a MonoTouch compiled library?

I have a MonoTouch license, and I'd love to do this so I can start embedding code MonoTouch code in new projects I work on that are conventional objective-c apps.

Does anyone have any examples or tutorials about how to do this?

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an article on embedding mono:

http://www.mono-project.com/Embedding_Mono

It is a little different in monotouch. There was a page explaining it on monotouch.net, but it appears to have been removed. http://monotouch.net/Documentation/XCode It looks like a copy of the content is located here:

http://www.guidebee.biz/forum/viewthread.php?tid=172

You basically run mtouch with the --xcode switch set on the output from your mono project. That will produce an xcode project with the fles needed to embed monotouch.

Comment: For future reference: The only problem with this solution is that they state very verbosely that this may not be available in the future. So this may not exist in future version of MonoTouch.