# Calling Mono libraries from native iPhone App

Tags: iphone, mono

how can I call Mono libraries right from a native iPhone App? It is written in Objective-C, so MonoTouch is no option.

Thanks in advance,
Alexander

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is there a way to make MonoTouch (runtime and associated library) a consumed and referenced library in a standard iOS project/application?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5177834/is-there-a-way-to-make-monotouch-runtime-and-associated-library-a-consumed-and)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably want to take a look at Mono's embedding API. You can find more info here: http://www.mono-project.com/Embedding_Mono